# Benefits of YARN

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

While reading about the benefits of YARN from this [video](http://zerotoprotraining.com/index.php?mode=video&id=1289), They said that there is Improved utilization of cluster as Scheduler optimizes cluster utilization. Scheduler bases the optimization on certain criteria i) Capacity guarantees ii)fairness iii)SLA’s So I was confuse, What is SLA's and how it works optimization for scheduling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YARN's capacity scheduler is designed to allow sharing of large cluster across many organizations. The cluster utilization takes into account the capacity guarantees, fairness and SLA's of the organizations for optimization. It provides a stringent set of limits to ensure that single application or user cannot consume disproportionate amount of resources in the cluster.

SLA's basically the timeline before which the job of a particular organization should be completed.

Comment: SLA's stands for? . And it means the only purpose of SLA's is to check the time of job and make sure it will finish it with in time, is it correct?

Comment: SLA actually stands for Service Level Agreement.  It is a term used inside the organization. Yes you are correct. It is also considered one of the factor for cluster optimization.